# Markdown not rendered in embedded gist

Tags: github, gist

My gist markdown is not rendering when I embed it. Is this a GitHub issue, or am I doing it wrong?

The gist:

https://gist.github.com/3094145

The non-rendering embedded gist:

http://jsfiddle.net/dJnBg/

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**2012-12-11 Update: Today github pushed out a [complete rewrite of gist.github.com](https://github.com/blog/1276-welcome-to-a-new-gist), and this is no longer a problem. For proof, see [screenshot](https://github.com/dergachev/redmine_gist/issues/3#issuecomment-11266685). **

It looks deliberate. It's worth noting that syntax highlighting still works in embeds, but not (alas) markdown rendering.

A potential workaround might be to add additional JS code (after the gist embed JS) that renders the markdown client-side, perhaps via http://www.showdown.im/

I made an issue for myself to do this for the redmine gist embed plugin I wrote. 
https://github.com/dergachev/redmine_gist/issues/3

Perhaps by the time you're reading this I got around to tackling this ;)